# PHP post for sms otp in android

Tags: php, android

I want php to receive post message, my code is like this:

```
<?php
    $phonenum = $_POST['phoneNum'];
    $otp = $_POST['OTP'];
    $post_data = array(
        'From'   => '8808891988',
        'To'    => $phonenum,
        'Body'  => $otp , 
    );
?>
```

when I am hard-coding the values 'To' and 'Body' its working but when I try to bring from post data it fails.

Kindly help!

My Android code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.in/sendansms/sendansms.php");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phoneNum", "9739109995"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OTP", "testcode"));

try {
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, "utf-8"));
    final HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    h.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: try this code to check whether you POST request working fine or not 
line 1) $phonenum =1;
line 2 ) $otp = 2;

Comment: nameValuePair is depricated. if you use this you face problem in future.

Comment: so what should i use ? @akhil

Comment: Dont use HttpClient and HttpPost. you have to use HttpUrlConnection the new one

Answer (score 0):

Just use this class. Add this class in your project.

```
package eazito.eazitoclient.miscs;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class  PutUtility {

    private Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    private static HttpURLConnection httpConnection;
    private static BufferedReader reader;
    private static String Content;
    private StringBuffer sb1;
    private StringBuffer response;

    public void setParams(Map<String, String> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    public void setParam(String key, String value) {
        params.put(key, value);
    }

    public String getData(String Url) {


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            // Defined URL  where to send data

            URL url = new URL(Url);

            URLConnection conn = null;
            conn = url.openConnection();

            // Send POST data request
            httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {

                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }


        return response.toString();
    }


    public String postData(String Url) {


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            String value = null;
            value = params.get(key);


            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append("&");
            }
            sb.append(key + "=" + value);
        }

        try {
            // Defined URL  where to send data

            URL url = new URL(Url);

            URLConnection conn = null;
            conn = url.openConnection();

            // Send POST data request
            httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = null;

            wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(sb.toString());
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {

                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }


        return response.toString();
    }


    public String putData(String Url) {


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            String value = null;
            try {
                value = URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), "UTF-8");
                if (value.contains("+"))
                    value = value.replace("+", "%20");

                //return sb.toString();


                // Get the server response

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append("&");
            }
            sb.append(key + "=" + value);
        }

        try {
            // Defined URL  where to send data

            URL url = new URL(Url);

            URLConnection conn = null;
            conn = url.openConnection();

            // Send PUT data request
            httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpConnection.setDoOutput(false);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = null;

            wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(sb.toString());
            wr.flush();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            ;
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Append server response in string
                sb1.append(line + " ");
            }

            // Append Server Response To Content String
            Content = sb.toString();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {

                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        // Send PUT data request
        return Url;

    }


    public String deleteData(String Url) {


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {

            try {
                // Defined URL  where to send data

                URL url = new URL(Url);

                URLConnection conn = null;
                conn = url.openConnection();

                // Send POST data request
                httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
                httpConnection.connect();


                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                String line = null;

                // Read Server Response
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Append server response in string
                    sb1.append(line + " ");
                }

                // Append Server Response To Content String
                Content = sb.toString();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {

                    reader.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }



        }
        return Url;

    }
}
```

How to Use this class.

```
try {
     PutUtility put = new PutUtility();

        put.setParam("phoneNum", "9739109995"));
        put.setParam("OTP","testcode" );

        res = put.postData("http://mysite.in/sendansms/sendansms.php");
} catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Hope it works for you. If you have any doubt ask me

Comment: can you explain if this ?    if(sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append("&");
            }
            sb.append(key + "=" + value);

Comment: what should be the php part?

Comment: yes i tried but it is not able to put post data, OTP is still empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90428/discussion-between-tushar-saha-and-akhil-batlawala).